Android JNI failing to create file but will open if created in kotlin
JNI is failing to create file with simple fopen. (it does create it, it seems, every once in a while, specially if I rename the filename inside the jni befor calling fopen)
If I simply create the file before calling the jni function it works(so if it already exists it will
tmp.createFile() // required
copyFile(f.toString(), tmp.toString())

in copyFile:
F = fopen(pathF, "rb");
T = fopen(pathT, "wb");

T is null unless tmp.createFile is called before the call to copyFile
Randomly every once it will work(without tmp.createFile) in a while for some reason, I think when I reboot. The errno is 2 File not found or whatever.
While creating the file in kotlin is not a problem I'm curious as to why it is failing in jni as it shouldn't.
Maybe there is a permissions issue but given that it does work every once in a while suggests it is something else.
